# 1V output only when load is applied?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, solid-state-relay

I'm working with the Teensy++ 2.0 dev. board. It uses the AT90USB1286 8 bit AVR 16 MHz microcontroller. I'm using the microcontroller to drive a small solid state relay.

[image: Schematic]

This was just a basic simulation that I ran. I am actually using a TLP222A relay instead of the MOC205. The 5V from the microcontroller, across the 390 ohm resistor (factoring the forward voltage of the diode) will give me ~12 mA of forward current. I have tested this circuit with a bench power supply as my "microcontroller" to supply 5V, and it worked great.

On my Teensy++ board, I am able to measure 5V at the pin with no load. But as soon as I connect it in the circuit, my voltage output is only about 1V.

```
void initialize (void) {
DDRB=0b11111111;
}

int main(void)
{
// set for 16 MHz clock, and make sure the LED is off
CPU_PRESCALE(0);
LED_CONFIG;
LED_OFF;

usb_init();

while(1) {
    PORTB = 0b11111111;
    LED_ON;
    _delay_ms(3000);
    PORTB = 0b00000000;
    LED_OFF;
    _delay_ms(3000);    
}
}
```

Above is a bit of my code. The main piece is that I set DDRB to outputs and then in my while loop I toggle the output on and off.

I trust that there is no issue with the resistor or relay, since they work properly when I use a bench power supply in place of the microcontroller. I have tested multiple pins/ports from the board.

Thank you for the help! It's much appreciated!

Comment: You would measure 1volt at v_f when the detector diode is conducting because the forward drop of the diode is in the range of one volt. How much drive current can your processor pin supply?

Comment: AVRs can usually source/sink 20mA easily, 40mA maximum.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a construction fault. Maybe a short across R1? A photo of your setup might help us guess what's going on.

Comment: When you measure 1V at "the pin", is that the AVR pin or the opto pin? I would expect 5V at the AVR and 1V at the opto (LED) Also, measure that resistor to check it's 390 ohms (marked 391) and not 39 ohms (marked 390)

Answer (score 1):

You are using 24VAC to feed the transistor output of an opto-coupler. That's plainly wrong and this won't work as you intend. The absolute maximum voltage rating for this device operated with a reverse polarity supply is 7 volts.

If you operated at DC 24V you are going to hit another problem and the opto might overheat. Even if you could push 12mA into the 390 ohm load the volt drop across the opto transistor would be about 19 volts and the internal power dissipation is 228mW. The device max rating for the transistor is 150mW.

The device has a current transfer ratio of about 60% - this means if you push 12mA into the diode, you can only expect 7.2mA coming out.

Comment: Sorry, the schematic is from the simulation I ran to test the operating principle of an optocoupler. I am actually using a TLP222A instead of the MOC205. I've tested this circuit with a bread board and a bench power supply acting as the "microcontroller" and it works fine.

Comment: So, what was the problem (other than the circuit in your question being incorrect)?